# Determining if a soft link already exists

Tags: symbolic-link

How can you determine if a soft link already exists? I do not know how to determine this. I am a novice to Unix/Linux

Answer (score 3):

As a user

```
$ ls -l
```

if the first character of the mode bits (first column) is `l` it's a link.

If you just want to test this from a script,

```
$ test -L maybealink && echo "it is a symlink"
```

Comment: You are assuming that the link is in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want to find symlinks to a specific file but don't know in what directory they may be. In that case type

```
find . -lname "path/to/filename" -ls
```

for instance

```
find . -lname "develop/source/itried.cpp" -ls
```

to find and show (starting in your current directory) any symlinks of the file named `itried.cpp` that lies in the directory `develop/source`.

or

```
find . -lname "*.cpp" -ls
```

to find symlinks to any `.cpp` files under your current directory.

the `.` after find tells it to search from your current directory down.

Comment: Note that the `-lname` is going to match the exact string content of the link, and so it may not match what you expect if the link is an absolute path or contains `..` etc.

Comment: @poolie, no, it is a shell pattern (not "exact string"), so you can determine what you want to find by some degree

Comment: It's a glob but it is matched against the string content of the link. So you can do that if you add wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

If there is soft-link in your current directory

Use `ll` command to display the file long list

Output will be like this

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    24 Dec  2  2011 default-java -> java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64/
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Oct  8 11:29 java-1.5.0-gcj-4.6/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    24 Dec  2  2011 java-1.6.0-openjdk -> java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    20 Jul 17 21:41 java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-6-openjdk-amd64/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2387 Jul 17 21:41 .java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
```

if there is l before rwrwrw its softlink

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    24 Dec  2  2011 default-java -> java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64/
```

This is a Softlink , java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 had been softlinked to default-java

Softlinks will be displayed in sky blue color